# UnsatisfiedLinkError -- Play! dependencies

Tags: java, playframework, dependencies, ivy, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Every time I try to resolve dependencies using Play 1.2.5(also tried 1.2.4) by typing `play dependencies` at the command line, I get the following error:

```
~ Resolving dependencies using C:\Workspace\moosejuice\conf\dependencies.yml,
~
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.findResourceUsingPattern(RepositoryResolver.java:104)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.findResourceUsingPatterns(AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.java:93)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.findIvyFileRef(AbstractPatternsBasedResolver.java:72)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:169)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:287)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:696)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:781)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:704)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:576)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:237)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:195)
        at play.deps.DependenciesManager.resolve(DependenciesManager.java:341)
        at play.deps.DependenciesManager.main(DependenciesManager.java:39)
```

I get this error even for freshly created projects, with no changes to `dependencies.yml`.  I thought maybe it was a permissions thing, but there are no limitations I can see on any of those folders, and I've tried `cmd.exe` in admin mode, as well as normal mode.

I'm fairly sure I've resolved dependencies on this machine before; what could have changed to give me this error?

**EDIT:**  I've tested now to see if it was an antivirus program, firewall, or microsoft security, but even with all of those off, no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

```
Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.
```

This exception means the jvm fails to resolve the native method `createFileExclusively` on java.io.WinNTFileSystem

This sounds a lot like a DLL loading problem which can be hell to debug. <s>I am trying to locate the dll containing the linked method but I haven't done that in a long time</s>  The dll which contains the native method definition is `java.dll` in jdk\jre\bin or in jre\bin

From various tests I was unable to reproduce the exact same issue. I would say you probably have in your dll load path a java.dll with a version which differs from the version of java.exe used by play.

The quickest would be to reinstall the jre/jdk used by play.

Comment: Well, I dunno about drivers and whatnot, but it seems to have just needed reinstallation.  Dependencies are resolving as I type!  I can reward bounty in 23 hours, it says.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) quick note : DLLs are not only drivers, you can think of a DLL as the equivalent of a jar but for native windows applications.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes from your Java installation, not from play. Did you tried using another version of Java (another JDK)? What version are you using?

You may install another JDK and configure your `PATH` so that `java` is pointing to a newer version and try running play again using this new Java version.

Comment: Using jdk 1.7 right now.  Gonna download 6 to try with that I guess